# ParseServer: not saving user info?

Tags: java, android, parse-platform, parse-server

Basically, if a user is located near a certain event, I want to update an attribute called "pending" to "yes". I'm using a for loop to iterate through all the users (this code is just for a demo purposes, there aren't that many users), and check their distance to the specified event. If they are <= 7000 away, then I want to update "pending" to "yes." However, none of the attributes are actually saving?

I have attached my whole code but the relevant snippet occurs after this comment:// ****** NOTIFICATIONS FOR USERS WHO LIVE IN THE NEIGHBOURHOOD ***********

THINGS I KNOW:

- the first log statement I put "numUsers" returns how many users are in the query, for me to validate that all of the users are actually queried. It returns 7, which is true! So that works.
- IN the for loop, it's successfully printing each users user name at each iteration, so I know it's properly iterating through the users.
- lastly, at u.SaveInBackground(....) it's successfully printing out each users name, and "yes" if they are within the distance I specified, or "null" if not.

but when I check the server none of this information is actually stored?
And outside of this method if I try to get any user's "pending" attribute, it will tell me it's null.

I've been stuck on this for hours now!

```
public void onButtonClickDecision(final View view) {

    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("IncidentReports");
    query.whereEqualTo("reference", intent.getStringExtra("reference"));
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(final List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                if (objects.size()>0) {

                    //if we clicked, decline -> update status to decline
                    if (view.getId() == R.id.decline) {
                        objects.get(0).put("status", "declined");
                    }
                    // if we clicked approve -> update status to approve
                    else if (view.getId() == R.id.approve) {
                        // update status
                        objects.get(0).put("status", "approved");


                        // ****** NOTIFICATIONS FOR USERS WHO LIVE IN THE NEIGHBOURHOOD ***********
                        ParseQuery<ParseUser> query3 = ParseUser.getQuery();
                        query3.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
                            @Override
                            public void done(List<ParseUser> users, ParseException e) {

                                Log.i("numUsers", Integer.toString(users.size()));

                                if ( e== null && users.size()>0) {

                                    // COMPARE EACH USERS ADDRESS
                                    for (final ParseUser u : users) {

                                        Log.i("user name", u.getUsername());
                                        String address = u.getString("address");

                                        try {
                                            // sets up users home as a Location
                                            List<Address> list = geocoder.getFromLocationName(address, 1);
                                            Address add = list.get(0);

                                            Location home = new Location(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                                            home.setLatitude(add.getLatitude());
                                            home.setLongitude(add.getLongitude());

                                            // check if user is located in incident neighbourhood
                                            if (home.distanceTo(incidentLoc) <= 7000) {
                                                u.put("pending", "yes");
                                            }


                                        } catch (IOException ex) {
                                            Log.i("ApprovedCheckingUsers", "failed");
                                            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
                                        }

                                        u.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void done(ParseException e) {
                                                Log.i("Updated:", u.getUsername() + "," + u.getString("pending"));
                                            }
                                        });
                                    }

                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }

                    // NOTIFY USER WHO POSTED
                    objects.get(0).put("notified", "false");

                    objects.get(0).put("reviewedby", ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getString("username"));
                    objects.get(0).saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void done(ParseException e) {
                            if (e == null) {
                                System.out.println("Saving status updates");
                                currentStatus.setText(objects.get(0).getString("status"));
                                Toast.makeText(ViewIndividualReport.this, "Status successfuly changed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            } else {
                                System.out.println("Failed to save");
                                Toast.makeText(ViewIndividualReport.this, "Could not update status at this time. Try again later.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });

                }

            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: If you print the `e` var of your `u.saveInBackground()` callback, you'll see there is an error there. For security reasons, Parse Server does not allow you to update user objects directly from the client code. It would be a security breach and anyone would be able to erase all your users table. So you need to create a cloud code function to perform this operation and call this cloud code function from the Android app.